# Are there any disadvantages to setting up My Domain?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom, mydomain

I would like to install custom Lightning components in my organization, but according to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214270&language=en_US&type=1 I need to set up My Domain for security purposes.

I tried to look for opinions regarding this. I found this article - http://www.lanefourdata.com/2016/11/17/why-you-should-set-up-my-domain-today/. It talks about the advantages of setting up My Domain. However, since this is irreversible, I would like to know if there are any disadvantages to setting up My Domain.

Answer (score 3):

Its a must that need to be done before creating and using lightning components in tabs,app builder etc. There aren't any major con's that i can think of which would affect you because of setting up my domain.

The only concern i can think of is you need to educate your users if they have bookmarked the old URL(login.salesforce.com) that it wont work once my domain is enabled and you prevent logging in from generic salesforce URL. This is only applicable if you have already deployed code to production.

below are some of the benefits and best practices. Read more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_overview.htm&type=5)

Creating a My Domain subdomain helps you better manage login and authentication for your org in several key ways. You can:

1. Highlight your business identity with your unique domain URL
2. Brand your login screen and customize right-frame content
3. Block or redirect page requests that don’t use the new domain name
4. Work in multiple Salesforce orgs at the same time
5. Set custom login policy to determine how users are authenticated
6. Let users log in using a social account, like Google and Facebook,
   from the login page
7. Allow users to log in once to access external services

My Domain is required before you can use these Salesforce features:

1. Single sign-on (SSO) with external identity providers
2. Social sign-on with authentication providers, such as Google and
   Facebook
3. Lightning components in Lightning component tabs, Lightning pages,
   the Lightning App Builder, or standalone apps

Answer (score 0):

There are considerations if you have published web services at your end. The system making calls to your endpoints often needs to be reconfigured to use the new domain.